# How can I read in C# XML from another page while logged in to the site

Tags: asp.net, authentication, session, webclient, xmltextreader

I have logged in to the site with my webbrowser and whenever I try to call

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
string str = myWebClient.DownloadString("http://localhost/myxml.aspx");
Response.Write(str.ToString());
```

Or

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(url);
while (reader.Read()) {
 Response.Write(reader.ReadOuterXml());
}
```

Response.Write returns me the login page.

Is there away to attach user SessionId to WebClient or XmlTextReader or how can I request another page in C# with current logged user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use an object that can handle storing cookies. In this case, you'll need the [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class. You'll also need a [`CookieContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) to manage authentication cookies.

To do this you would:

1. Create a `CookieContainer` object (a cookie jar) that you can keep track of throughout the scope of every request you make.
2. Create an `HttpWebRequest` that logs into the site you're accessing.
3. Use the `CookieContainer` you created in step 1 for every subsequent request.

Below is an example of how to use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx), and [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) classes together to make a simple request that will set some cookies, and then using those cookies on a subsequent request. The rest should be easy assuming everything is well formed markup ;)

```
CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
webRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    Response.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
}

var anotherWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow.com");
anotherWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

webResponse = anotherWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Another option (if you really want to use the `WebClient` class) would be to parse out the `ResponseHeaders` property of the class once you've made your request and include the appropriate cookies in your next request. This is a little more involved though since it requires you to manage your cookies manually.

Since I'm assuming that you want to be able to traverse your web responses as XML, I suggest you look into the open source library, [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack). It allows you to send in markup from a web site that is (most likely) not well-formed, or has some sort of invalid markup in it, and then fixes the invalid parts so that you can traverse it like XML.

Answer (score 1):

While doing some screen scraping, I had the same issue. I was requesting a Classic ASP app on an IIS server (I could tell by some of the headers that the server reponded with). The way I supported an ongoing session was by enabling Cookies on the WebClient. Theres no toggle for it, you have to subclass WebClient to get it to work.

```
    public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
    {
        protected CookieContainer _container = new CookieContainer();

        public CookieContainer Cookies
        {
            get { return _container; }
            set { _container = value; }
        }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;      

            if (httpRequest.CookieContainer != null)
            {
                if (httpRequest != null)
                {
                    CookieCollection newCookies = 
                        GetUniqueCookies(
                                address
                                ,httpRequest.CookieContainer.GetCookies(address)
                                );
                    foreach (Cookie c in newCookies)
                        httpRequest.CookieContainer.Add(c);
                }
            }
            else
                httpRequest.CookieContainer = this.Cookies;

            return (WebRequest)httpRequest;
        }
```

Note: this isn't a unique solution, I found this out there on the web myself, but I've implemented the solution and it works really well.